# Linking Title to an URL in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I am just new to Drupal and trying to update some existing applications. I am trying to associate the `title` to an URL. I tried this

```
link(title, content.field_url)
```

But I don't think I am right track. Any help would be appreciated. Following is the twig templet for displaying persons.

```
<div class="wdn-col" style="margin-top:2.4em;">
<div class="wdn-grid-set">
  <div class="wdn-col-three-sevenths">
    <div class="wdn-frame">{{ (content.field_portrait) }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wdn-col-four-sevenths">
    <h5 class="wdn-brand clear-top">{{title }} 
      <span class="wdn-subhead">{{ (content.field_position) }}, {{ (content.field_institution) }}</span></h5>
    <p style="font-size:smaller;">{{ (content.field_unit) }}</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:{{ (content.field_email_address) }}">{{ (content.field_email_address) }}</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where you trying to create a link i did not find in your code

Comment: I tried `<h5 class="wdn-brand clear-top">{{link(title, content.field_url) }}` which throws some error.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way....

```
    <a href="{{ content.field_url }}">{{ title }}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Ujjval ! It worked. The one mistake I was doing is that the `field_url` type was `link` instead of `text`.